# jquery each loop doesnot print the text

Tags: jquery

```
$.each( headings, function() {
      $('#heading').append($("<option />",{ value: this, text: this }));
});
```

the html validator shows this

```
<option value="abc"></option>
<option value="xyz"></option>
</select>
```

The text for the option is not getting printed. if i use a hash it works fine though

Comment: What does `headings` look like?

Comment: I'm not saying you're lying, but it seems highly unlikely that it would work with the value and not the text, and it works just fine here -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PNzuJ/).

Comment: well i just copy pasted from the fiddle and still the same for me . the option values are picked as shown from the fire bug

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bDn2A/

Comment: which is the jquery version used

Comment: This is the select tag with id heading
   <select id='heading' name='heading'><option value='1'>A_Z</option> </select>

Comment: * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.5.1

Comment: Are you using the latest jQuery version, did you add a document ready function, what the heck is a HTML validator ?

Comment: Use a newer version of jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each( headings, function() {
      $('#heading').append($("<option value="+this+">"+this+"</option>"));
});
```

Comment: Actually, the OP is doing it the right way, while your answer is doing it the wrong way.